# Possible to create WinForm apps in VB.NET that can access an intranet?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, networking, intranet, share

I'm not looking for a solution, rather I just want to know if this is possible or not with VB.NET (which I'm still just a beginner on).

What I'm looking to develop is a WinForm application that allows users within the company network to share files and other information.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please clarify. Windows by itself can permit users to share files and other information. Also, a Winforms application is usually used by each user individually. It doesn't usually act as a server for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have LOTS of ways to do this, depending on the your requirements. You are basically building a distributed app, and .NET has some very strong technologies for this.

First of all, the most simple solution is to create a shared folder, and then create a program that uses that folder for communication (periodic checks for changes, etc...)

Second solution would perhaps be a ASP.NET web service, also depending what info you want to share.

At the end, the most powerful solution would be TCP/IP Sockets, but that is really for VERY fast, and VERY concurrent requirements.

Since you didn't fully describe what you want to do, I suggest you do a "distributed programming .NET" or "network programming .NET" search on the Google.

There are plenty of examples using all sorts of techniques, either in VB or C# (and you can also translate code from one to another).

Comment: great, thanks.  I'm not even in the designing stage yet, I'm just thinking of different applications that might be needed and this struck me as one of them.  When I get further along I'll probably reach out for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure... either through a networked folder, or through a user-control. Really depends on what you are really going to be doing. Sorry I cannot be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll need to give more specifics on what you want to do.